# Cópia de banco de dados WordPress sem utilizar o PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress

Preciso fazer a migração de um site em WordPress de um servidor para outro. Um dos passos necessários é exportar o banco de dados utilizado no site atual, editar alguns dados caso necessário (como o endereço do site e as URLs dos arquivos) e importar o banco de dados para o novo servidor.

É possível fazer este processo de exportar/importar sem a utilização do PHPMyAdmin, somente com os dados de acesso ao banco de dados (nome do banco, servidor, login e senha)? Existe alguma ferramenta que permita acessar o banco de dados sem estar instalada no próprio servidor?

Comment: Talvez o mysqldump sirva neste caso.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao servidor por linha de comando (SSH)?

Comment: Não, acredito que não...os dois servidores estão em um serviço como Locaweb ou Uolhost.
É que na verdade não é um caso específico, este é um procedimento que eu preciso fazer quase sempre e não é toda vez que eu consigo acesso ao phpmyadmin com facilidade

Comment: O wordpress tem o próprio sistema de importação/exportação de dados em "Ferramentas". Basta acessar o wp-admin e selecionar o conteúdo (ou todo ele) e exportar. Ele gera um arquivo zipado, daí é só ir no outro servidor, na mesma página "Ferramentas" mas agora na opção "importação".

Comment: Sim, mas a exportação que ele gera não vem (acredito) em SQL e não inclui todas as informações da instalação do Wordpress. Essa exportação é útil para alguns casos, mas para a migração de um servidor para outro fica BEM mais fácil exportar e importar diretamente o banco.

Comment: Olha, se for na Locaweb sei que tem SSH. Pela linha de comando você consegue exportar facilmente com o comando `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [WP-DB-Backup](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-backup/)

Existe um plugin para Wordpress que realiza o backup, o WP-DB-Backup, onde podemos ler na página do mesmo:

> WP-DB-Backup allows you easily to backup your core WordPress database tables. You may also backup other tables in the same database.

Que traduzido:

> WP-DB-Backup permite facilmente realizar um backup das tabelas de configuração presentes na base-de-dados do WordPress. Você também pode efectuar uma cópia de segurança de outras tabelas presentes na mesma base-de-dados.

## Instalação

A instalação é conseguida em quatro simples passos que pode ser [vistos aqui](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-backup/installation/):

1. Extrair a pasta `wp-db-backup/` para `/wp-content/plugins/`;
2. Activar o plugin na área administrativa em Admin -> Plugins;
3. O plugin vai tentar criar uma directoria com o nome `/wp-content/backup-*/` dentro da directoria do WordPress;
4. Pode ser necessário dar permissões de escrita à directoria `/wp-content` (pelo menos temporáriamente) para que o plugin consiga criar a directoria mencionada no ponto 3.

   Por exemplo:

   ```
   $ cd /wordpress/
   $ chgrp www-data wp-content (onde "www-data" é o grupo que o teu cliente de FTP utiliza)
   $ chmod g+w wp-content
   ```

Answer (score 9):

## Exportação visual a partir do painel administrativo (sem código)

Uma excelente alternativa que uso para esse tipo de tarefa é o plugin gratuito [**All-in-One WP Migration**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/), que permite a exportação e a importação do banco de dados SQL (ou de todos os arquivos do site, se preferir), a partir do próprio painel do WordPress, sem ser preciso lidar com FTP e permissões de arquivo, **de forma totalmente visual**.

A instalação do plugin é feita pelo próprio painel do WordPress em "`Plugins > Adicionar Novo`". Procure por "*All-in-One WP Migration*".

[image: Instalando o plugin pelo instalador nativo do WordPress]

Após a instalação a operação é simples:

1. **No site A:** Vá até o menu `Site Migration > Export` exporte o banco de dados (ou o site completo) com o plugin. Em alguns momentos ele gerará um arquivo com a extensão `.zip`;
2. **No site B:** Vá até o menu `Site Migration > Import` e arraste o arquivo `.zip` gerado na etapa 1 para dentro da área de importação.

E pronto!

O plugin funciona muito bem e pode ser inclusive utilizado por clientes, para um backup rápido do site completo ou somente do banco de dados, bastando acionar algumas opções bem simples.

Outra função importante do plugin é a **busca e substituição totalmente visual** do endereço do site e outras informações (como o caminho do servidor), que **precisam** ser alteradas no banco de dados final para permitir que o site funcione corretamente após a exportação.

[image: Tela de exportação do site a partir do plugin]

Uso o plugin com frequëncia nos meus projetos e recomendo a todos.

Comment: Fantástico! Já fiz um teste local e funcionou bem, criou o pacote com os temas, plugins e o sql do banco...o que mais gostei foi dessa opção de já fazer a substituição da URL no banco de dados exportado. Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Enrique_Trevelin, sucesso com os seus projetos!

Comment: @MarcioDuarte  
Estou terminando o meu primeiro blog em wordpress e estou muito preocupada,pois queria um backup completo de todo o site, incluindo banco de dados, plugins, configurações de plugins, e tudo mais... Quando você diz "exporte o banco de dados (ou o site completo) com o plugin" é isso mesmo, até mesmo as configurações estão salvas? Minha preocupação é o seguinte: Em um determinado dia, eu perco tudo do site, posts e etc...Gostaria de pegar o backup e simplesmente colocar o site no ar de novo como se nada tivesse acontecido...Desde já agradeço a atenção. ;)

Comment: Sim, @marcielli, ele pode exportar tudo mesmo. É só selecionar todas as opções (deixá-las em verde). Você pode baixar um backup para o seu computador ou salvar no Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. A restauração pode ser feita mesmo se o site atual "quebrar" totalmente.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Vou tentar fazer isso então. Obrigada pela atenção. ;) @MarcioDuarte

Answer (score 5):

## [**Adminer**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/)

O plugin é um PHPMyAdmin dentro do WordPress. É uma ferramenta completa de administração do banco de dados MySQL escrita em PHP.

O autor do plugin, [Frank Bültge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/170/bueltge), é um craque da escola alemã de WordPress, só tenho elogios ao seu trabalho: [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/), [BackWPup](http://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/), [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) e um largo *et cetera* de outros plugins, projetos no GitHub e participação no Stack Exchange WordPress Developers.

**Tela principal**

[image: Tela principal do Adminer]

**Tela de controle** (seção *Dump*, usando <kbd>Start Adminer inside</kbd>)

[image: Tela de controle do Adminer]

---

### Edição dos dados exportados

Para isso utilizo o seguinte procedimento:

- Importar o *dump* MySQL numa base de dados local ou uma outra vazia no servidor.
- Usar o aplicativo [**Database Search and Replace Script in PHP**](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) para substituir tudo que for necessário (URLs e Paths, principalmente).
- Exportar essa base modificada e importar no servidor final.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma ferramenta do MySQL chamada [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) que pessoalmente acho mais prático que usar do que o phpMyAdmin. É possivel fazer muitas coisas com ela, inclusive importar e exportar o banco de dados. Porem, requer instalação no seu computador, o que não sei se vai ser um problema para você.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/download), assim, não precisará de plugins ou terceiros. Criará uma conexão direta entre os servidores.

E [aqui um video-tutorial](http://vimeo.com/12366049) bem legal de como utilizá-lo.

Comment: Boa resposta mas se for possível tente postar o link do navicat ou até mesmo o link da documentação ;) upvote

Answer (score 0):

Depois de pesquisar muito! O melhor plugin gratuito de backup do banco é o UpDraftPlus: https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/
Tem mais de 800 mil instalações ativas, suporte rápido e nota 4.9/5 estrelas.

Comment: O Updraft é mesmo fantástico, mas para migrar entre sites – que foi a pergunta original – é preciso comprar um módulo adicional, o Updraf Migrations: https://updraftplus.com/faqs/how-do-i-migrate-to-a-new-site-location/